# User defined data types in standard SQL (BigQuery)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is it possible to create user defined data types in standard SQL, which can then be referenced from within the SQL code itself?

As an example, let's say I wanted to create a function that would take two instances of `STRUCT` - each containing three entries of type `STRING`. This would require writing something like this;

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION myFunc(x STRUCT<STRING, STRING, STRING>, y STRUCT<STRING, STRING, STRING>) AS (...);
```

What I want to do though, is something like this (pseudo-code);

```
CREATE TYPE myType STRUCT<STRING, STRING, STRING>
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION myFunc(x myType, y myType) AS (...)
```

Comment: No unfortunately, it's not possible. You still have to use the first method.

Comment: If you think this would be a useful feature for BigQuery you can add a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685

Answer (score 1):

Something similar would be using ANY TYPE to create your function like:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION myFunc(x ANY TYPE, y ANY TYPE) AS (...);
```

To answer question in comments, if strong type check is needed, you can still do something like this and use to check parameter of myFunc() to report an error if type is incompatible:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION check_type_x(x ANY TYPE) AS (STRUCT(x.a, x.b, x.c));


SELECT myFunc(check_type_x(col1), check_type_x(col2));
```

Comment: This is not similar to having a user-defined type. The ANY TYPE clause allows parameters of any data type to be passed to the function, so BigQuery does not attempt to validate the data type at all when the function is called. This is basically the opposite effect of a user-defined data type (if they existed in BigQuery), which is to make the data type definition *more* restrictive than the default types.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths I agree with all that you said. But still, it is *possible* that syntactic sugar is all that needed here. If inside the function, x.a, x.b and x.c are all referenced, BigQuery still gives you an error message if the passed in type doesn't have them. It means you can defined a function `CREATE FUNCTION type_x(x ANY TYPE) AS (STRUCT(x.a, x.b, x.c));` to have your type checked ANY TYPE type.

Comment: Also added a small hack to my answer for type check @NathanGriffiths.